# Most convenient way to perform inline row editing using Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a List of some objects, which are returned to the View using Spring's Model attribute. 
I'm iterating through this list by using standard forEach of JSTL.
I want to introduce inline edit opportunity of some values of the row.

Now I have quick & dirty solution: just getting a new value by generated id of the input field directly from `HttpRequest` object in Controller on POST.

I believe there should be more handy way from Spring to achieve this. Has someone deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@ModelAttribute`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods) annotation to map HttpRequest into some custom object which will be hold all data you need.